# Receive HTTP POST in Controller of my Magento Custom Module

Tags: magento, http-post

I'm learning to develop modules magento. I'm developing a payment module and it should receive a post (after closing the application) to change the status of the request and generate the invoice.

But I do not know how to get on my HTTP POST controller. I will make a post at http://mymagento.com/mymodule/receive.

```
class MyCompanyName_MyModule_StandardController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function receiveAction() {
        //How receive my POST HERE??
    }

    // ...

}
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [`Zend_Controller_Request_Http::getPost()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php#L317):

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost();
// or
$this->getRequest()->getPost('param');
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. And if I want to answer information, eg a JSON, it would be possible? How should I proceed?

Comment: Can I use `$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id')` too?

Comment: You can always use it. If it's being passed, that will retrieve it.

Comment: Hi Ben, Did you mean `$this->getRequest()->getPost();`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getContent();
```