# Magento share wishlist, how to get recipients emails?

Tags: magento, observers

I am working on a plugin for magento and I have created observer for share wishlist action, but I need to know email addresses that customer wrote in a box. Do you have any idea, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question, if someone would have the same issue, just read the $_POST variable "emails"

Comment: You might want to do it [the Magento way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12380831/1737136).